# Throughput comes in hrs what is mean that server performance is good or not?

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Please help me about below summary report.what a server performance if throughput is in hrs.

Throughput comes in hrs what is mean that server performance is good or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Throughput** - the Throughput is measured in requests per second/minute/hour.

The *time unit* is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0.

When you have throughput in hours means the throughput is low. 
If you have not controlled the throughput explicitly , it means that server+network performance is low with respect to your JMeter client.

**Note** 
When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.